# Inverse moment of Multivariate Normal Norm

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, expected-value

Let $x \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ with $\mu \in \mathbb{R}^P$; $\Sigma \in \mathbb{R}^{P\times P}$, positive definite. Denote by $||x||_2$ the vector two norm, that is, $||x||_2 = \sqrt{x^\top x}$.

What is $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{||x||_2}]$?

What about $\mathbb{E}[\frac{1}{||x||_2^2}]$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the so-called [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) to write the integral you need to compute.   In this case, we are asked to calculate the first and second moments of the reciprocal distribution 1/x.

\begin{align} \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{ |x|^n  } \right]  =&  \int d x^p \frac{1}{ \sqrt{(2 \pi)^p   \det(\Sigma) }   } \frac{1}{|x|^n} \\ & \times \exp \left( - \frac{1}{2}  (x - \mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x- \mu)   \right)      \end{align}

We can study the behavior of the integrand around $r=0$ using polar coordinates.  The integrals go like

$$ \mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{1}{ |x|^n  } \right]   \sim \int r^{p-1-n} dr \ldots   $$

where dots represent convergent pieces and $r = |x|$. The integrals diverge for $p-1-n<0$, so for $n=1$ it is divergent for $p<2$ and for $n=2$ it is divergent for $p <3$.  In these cases where the moment diverges it is said not to exist.   See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646428/mean-and-variance-of-reciprocal-normal-distribution) for the univariate normal distribution discussion.

Answer (score 2):

For the case where $\Sigma = \mathbf{I}\sigma$, we have the following formulas:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{1}{||x||} \right) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} {}_1F_1 \left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{P}{2}, -\frac{||\frac{\mu}{\sigma}||^2}{2}\right) \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{P-1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{P}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left( \frac{1}{||x||^2} \right) = \frac{1}{2} {}_1F_1 \left(1, \frac{P}{2}, -\frac{||\frac{\mu}{\sigma}||^2}{2}\right) \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{P-2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{P}{2}\right)}
\end{equation}

where ${}_1F_1 \left(a,b,c\right)$ is the hypergeometric confluent function, and $||\frac{\mu}{\sigma}||^2$ is the squared norm of the distribution mean divided by the isotropic noise standard deviation $\sigma$ above.

The first expression I got from the sympy Python package (symbolic computation), with the following code

```
from sympy.stats import ChiNoncentral, density, E
from sympy import Symbol, simplify
# Define some symbols to use
k = Symbol("k", integer=True)
l = Symbol("l")
z = Symbol("z")
# Define the chi noncentral distribution
X = ChiNoncentral("x", k, l)
# Get the analytic expression for the first moment of the distribution
analyticExp = simplify(E(1/X))
```

Note, in simplifying the first expression from the code below, I used the Kummer relation.

These expressions, and other related ones, are derived in "Intermediate Probability: A Computational Approach", M. Paolella, section 10.1.2. In that section, an expression for the moments of the non-centered Chi-square variable are shown. You get these expressions by applying the formula to moments -1 and -2 of the non-cented Chi-Square.

This can be generalized to some other $\Sigma$'s. The Mathai and Provost book "Quadratic Forms in Random Variables" specifies in Theorem 5.1.3 the specific $\Sigma$'s under which $X^T X$, with $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$, is distributed as a non-central chi square distribution with non-centrality parameter $\delta^2$ and $r$ degrees of freedom. For those cases, you can just apply the formulas above, subtituting the corresponding non-centrality parameter and degrees of freedom. The $\Sigma$'s for which this holds, however, seem to be quite limited (e.g. they have to satisfy $\Sigma^3 = \Sigma^2$, which is almost to say that it is idempotent).

Comment: By the way, I am looking for the more general solution to the problem, where $\Sigma$ is any positive-definite or semi-definite matrix. Did you come across any approximations or insights about how to solve this problem?

Comment: Hey, thanks for this answer, very interesting. Tragically I haven't gotten any smarter in the last 3 years, but I'm absolutely interested in the general case as well. (For me, $x$ is from a gaussian process, so definitely $\Sigma$ is a general dense matrix).